# Stripe ElementsConsumer with TypeScript: Pass prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, stripe-payments

I'm using TypeScript 3.8 with ReactJs, using class-style components, and I'm following an example here: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react

In these docs, they show the use of the ElementsConsumer as such:

```
const InjectedCheckoutForm = () => {
  return (
    <ElementsConsumer>
      {({elements, stripe}) => (
        <CheckoutForm elements={elements} stripe={stripe} />
      )}
    </ElementsConsumer>
  );
};
```

This works fine. But I'd like to pass my own prop into the inner  like :

```
<InjectedCheckoutForm backgroundColor={"Green"} />
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this? I can't tell if I should add a parameter here:

```
const InjectedCheckoutForm = (backgroundColor: string) => {
      return (
       ....???
```

Also, does this qualify as a "high order component?" I haven't seen this style of wrapping a component before. The closest thing I've seen is the Redux 'connect' function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';

interface TestInterface {
  backgroundColor: string
}

const InjectedCheckoutForm: FC<TestInterface> = props => {
  ...
  const x = props.backgroundColor;
  ...
  return (
    <View style={{ 'backgroundColor': x }}>Hello boy<View>
  )
}
```

OR SIMPLE

```
const InjectedCheckoutForm = ({backgroundColor}) => {
  ...
  const x = backgroundColor
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It took writing this out for me to figure it out. I'm less experienced with functional components, but the key was moving from

```
const InjectedCheckoutForm = () => {
    return (
        <ElementsConsumer>
            {({ elements, stripe }) => (
                <CreditCardForm backgroundColor={???} elements={elements} stripe={stripe} />
            )}
        </ElementsConsumer>
    );
};
```

to

```
const InjectedCheckoutForm = (props) => {
    return (
        <ElementsConsumer>
            {({ elements, stripe }) => (
                <CreditCardForm backgroundColor={props.backgroundColor} elements={elements} stripe={stripe} />
            )}
        </ElementsConsumer>
    );
};
```

(Props are wrapped in a single 'props' parameter.)

I hope this is helpful to others who may have had the same question.